# Symfony 3.4 + Propel configuration Error

Tags: symfony, propel

I have install sysmfony 3.4 and try to setup propel and get below error. below is my composer.json file

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "propel/propel": "2.0.*@dev",
        "propel/propel-bundle": "~2.0@dev"
    },
```

I have try to below command.

```
C:/>  composer update
```

Get below error:

> - Installation request for propel/propel-bundle 2.0.0-alpha4 -> satisfiable by propel/propel-bundle[2.0.0-alpha4].
> - propel/propel-bundle 2.0.0-alpha4 requires symfony/symfony ~2.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.4.x-dev, 2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev,
>     2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, v2.4.0, v2.4.0-BETA1, v2.4.0-BETA2, v2.4.0-RC1, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7,
>     v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-BETA1, v2.5.0-BETA2, v2.5.0-RC1,
>     v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5,
>     v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.0-BETA1, v2.6.0-BETA2,
>     v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4,
>     v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.0-BETA1,
>     v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14,
>     v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21,
>     v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28,
>     v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35,
>     v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7,
>     v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.0-BETA1, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11,
>     v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18,
>     v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25,
>     v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32,
>     v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9] but these conflict
>     with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Please help me for fixed issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony 3.4 the below should sort the issue.

Add these lines to your composer.json

```
"propel/propel-bundle": "3.0.x-dev",
"propel/propel": "dev-master",
```